# Is it possible to scan for iBeacon advertisement data using Corebluetooth in the "background"?

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to be able to scan for iBeacons ad data using the CoreBluetooth framework in the background with known proximity UUIDs. I was able to scan for all the peripherals in the FOREGROUND using:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];
[self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
```

I tried doing this while the app entered background but it did not return any data. Is it even possible to scan for iBeacons using the Corebluetooth framework in the background?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the [Core Bluetooth Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/CoreBluetoothBackgroundProcessingForIOSApps/PerformingTasksWhileYourAppIsInTheBackground.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH7-SW1)

> When an app that implements the central role includes the
>   UIBackgroundModes key with the bluetooth-central value in its
>   Info.plist file, the Core Bluetooth framework allows your app to run
>   in the background to perform certain Bluetooth-related tasks. While
>   your app is in the background you can still discover and connect to
>   peripherals, and explore and interact with peripheral data
>
> Although you can perform many Bluetooth-related tasks while your app
>   is in the background, keep in mind that scanning for peripherals while
>   your app is in the background operates differently than when your app
>   is in the foreground. In particular, when your app is scanning for
>   device while in the background:
>
> - The CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey scan option key is
>     ignored, and multiple discoveries of an advertising peripheral are
>     coalesced into a single discovery event.
> - If all apps that are scanning
>     for peripherals are in the background, the interval at which your
>     central device scans for advertising packets increases. As a result,
>     it may take longer to discover an advertising peripheral.

You should confirm that you have specified the background mode key in your project settings and that your `CBCentralManager` instance is instantiated correctly.

I note, however, that your Bluetooth scanning code isn't particularly efficient even for foreground processing.  Shouldn't include the duplicates key unless it is strictly necessary and you should specify the service UUID that you are interested in rather than nil.

Comment: Thanks Paul, the bluetooth-central is set in the plist and the CBCentralManager is running properly and I'm able to get data in the foreground. The same implementation doesn't work in the background. Is it possible to scan for advertisement data or iBeacon data in the background using Corebluetooth framework?

Comment: You can't scan for iBeacons using Core Bluetooth.  If the iBeacon also advertises other BLE services (many do for configuration etc) then you should be able to scan for those.  I didn't find it in the documentation but I recall seeing somewhere that scanning for `nil` won't work in the background - you need to scan for a specific service